# sql view as per other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Given the table `Customers`, example:

```
CustomerID  FirstName   MiddleInitial   LastName
64          Abby        A               Garcia
65          Abby        C               Mehta
66          Abby        E               Chandra
67          Abby        J               Kapoor
68          Abby        J               Sanchez
69          Abby        K               Kovár
70          Abby        L               Sai
71          Abby        M               Lopez
72          Abby        P               Gonzalez
73          Abby        P               Rana
```

I would like to restrict the access to (table, column, row) as per definition in the other table, let's say `m_Customers` with definitions such as:

```
MetadataID  Field           Type        Access
1           Customers       table       "Group1","Group2","Group3"
2           MiddleInitial   column      "Group1","Group3"
3           18              row         "Group1","Group3"
```

Based on that, how do you formulate a query which ensures that if you are:

- from *Group3" you can't see column `MiddleInitials` and row with `CustomerId = 18`
- from "Group4" you can't see the data in Customers table

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the groups, are they roles known to the DBMS? If yes I'd rather write a view for each role, granting access on that view to the role and revoking access to the table. If not, you could write a table function you pass the group, that uses dynamic SQL. But your logic seems a bit strange to me: Why is the first rule in your rule table a "grant" rule and the others are "deny" rules?

Comment: You're not storing `"Group1","Group2","Group3"` as a single string are you?  That's surely three rows in link table?

Comment: @MatBailie string, I was thinking to use pattern matching

Comment: No, just no.  You don't store lists as strings in ***relational*** databases.  You may as well not be using a ***relational*** database.

Comment: You might be able to pull this off with a view with tons of `EXISTS`, but you can't modify the amount of columns you will select (you can force to return NULL values when there is a restriction). The best way would be using dynamic SQL, which can only be inside a SP. There seems to be a contradiction with your 2 examples, if your table holds the things you *can't* see then Group4 should be able to see everything.

Comment: This is a nightmare about to unfold. Dynamic sql everywhere and denormalized table structures. Your m_customer table violates 1NF. Yuck!!! And why are you doing this at such a micromanagement level. Seriously, preventing individual rows? It might be a good idea to revisit the requirements here. Something seems very off to me.

Comment: Why don't you just create two views one for each group while using permissions to control who can use what group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your exclusions and inclusions are mixed.  You have Group3 included with column Customers and row 18, but Group 4 not included with table Customers.  Make your m_Customers table include only those that have access or only those that are restricted -- not both.

It would typically be faster and easier to manage to change your data structure for m_Customers to use a record for every group.

```
MetadataID  Field           Type    Access
1           Customers       table   Group1
2           Customers       table   Group2
3           Customers       table   Group3
4           MiddleInitial   column  Group1
5           MiddleInitial   column  Group3
6           18              row     Group1
7           18              row     Group3
```

Here are two options; you can check for performance.

```
SELECT MAX(col.customerID) AS customerID, MAX(col.FirstName) AS FirstName, MAX(col.MiddleInitial) AS MiddleIntitial, MAX(col.LastName) AS LastName
FROM Customers AS c
INNER JOIN m_Customers AS mRow ON mRow.[Type] = 'row' AND mRow.CustomerID = c.Field AND mRow.Access = @group
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        IIF(mCol.Field = 'customerID', c.customerID, NULL) AS customerID,
        IIF(mCol.Field = 'Firstname', c.FirstName, NULL) AS FirstName,
        IIF(mCol.Field = 'MiddleInitial', c.FirMiddleInitialstName, NULL) AS MiddleInitial,
        IIF(mCol.Field = 'LastName', c.LastName, NULL) AS LastName
    FROM Customers AS c
    INNER JOIN  m_Customers AS mCol ON mCol.[Type] = 'column' AND mCol.Field = 'MiddleInitial' AND mCol.Access = @group
    ) AS col ON col.customerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP BY col.customerID, col.FirstName, col.MiddleInitial, col.LastName
```

or

```
SELECT customerID.customerID, FirstName.FirstName, MiddleInitial.MiddleInitial, LastName.LastName
FROM Customers AS c
INNER JOIN m_Customers AS mRow ON mRow.[Type] = 'row' AND mRow.CustomerID = c.Field AND mRow.Access = @group
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c.customerID
    FROM Customers AS c
    INNER JOIN  m_Customers AS mCol ON mCol.[Type] = 'column' AND mCol.Field = 'customerID' AND mCol.Access = @group
    ) AS customerID ON customerID.customerID = c.customerID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c.customerID, c.FirstName
    FROM Customers AS c
    INNER JOIN  m_Customers AS mCol ON mCol.[Type] = 'column' AND mCol.Field = 'FirstName' AND mCol.Access = @group
    ) AS FirstName ON FirstName.customerID = c.customerID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c.customerID, c.MiddleInitial
    FROM Customers AS c
    INNER JOIN  m_Customers AS mCol ON mCol.[Type] = 'column' AND mCol.Field = 'MiddleInitial' AND mCol.Access = @group
    ) AS MiddleInitial ON MiddleInitial.customerID = c.customerID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c.customerID, c.LastName
    FROM Customers AS c
    INNER JOIN  m_Customers AS mCol ON mCol.[Type] = 'column' AND mCol.Field = 'LastName' AND mCol.Access = @group
    ) AS LastName ON LastName.customerID = c.customerID
```

Consider changing the name of your column from Type to a non-reserved word.